# Issue with Redis removing Breadcrumbs Magento

Tags: magento, caching, redis, breadcrumbs

Hello stackoverflow community.

I'm been handed over a site that uses Redis, however i've not done much work with it before. It seems that for some reason it is removing breadcrumbs from the product view. As soon as a flush Redis they reappear for a while then disappear again.

Does anyone know of an issue with Redis with regards to breadcrumbs or does anyone know of an affective way to hole punch the breadcrumbs so they aren't cached ?

Thanks in advance for any advice.